# prefs.putBoolean within onPageFinished

Tags: java, android

I have the following which successfully amends the state of a boolean correctly:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wv);
    //Enable JavaScript
    wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    wv.setFocusable(true);
    wv.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    //Set Render Priority To High
    wv.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
    wv.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
    wv.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    wv.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
    wv.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    wv.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);

    //Load Url
    wv.loadUrl("https://str8red.com/");
    wv.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());

    SharedPreferences.Editor prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit();
    prefs.putBoolean("notifications_team_pick",false);
    prefs.putBoolean("notifications_results", false);

    prefs.commit();

}
```

However, when I wish to set the state of the Boolean within the onPageFinished in the code below it errors:

```
public class myWebClient extends WebViewClient {

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);

        String CurrentURL = wv.getUrl();

        if (CurrentURL == "https://str8red.com/") {
            wv.evaluateJavascript("fromAndroid()", new ValueCallback<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onReceiveValue(String value) {
                    String[] separated = value.split(" ");
                    //separated[0]; // logged in True Or False
                    //separated[1]; // Notifications 1 or 0
                    //separated[2]; // More Notifications or 1 or 0
                    String loggedIn = separated[0].replace("\"", "");
                    String Notify1 = separated[1].replace("\"", "");
                    String Notify2 = separated[2].replace("\"", "");

                    SharedPreferences.Editor prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit();
                    prefs.putBoolean("notifications_team_pick",false);
                    prefs.putBoolean("notifications_results", true);

                    prefs.commit();
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

The end game is to have the "Notify1" and "Notify2" set the state of the boolean.  But first steps is just setting the state of the boolean after the onPageFinished runs.

I hope I have explained myself properly, any help would be appreciated.  Many thanks, Alan.

Complete Code:

```
package com.str8red.str8red;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.ValueCallback;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    WebView wv;
    Boolean fish;
    Boolean shark;

    // When Back Pressed Go Back
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (wv.canGoBack()) {
            wv.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wv);
        //Enable JavaScript
        wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        wv.setFocusable(true);
        wv.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        //Set Render Priority To High
        wv.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
        wv.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
        wv.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        wv.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
        wv.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        wv.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);

        //Load Url
        wv.loadUrl("https://str8red.com/");
        // wv.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
        wv.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient(this));

        SharedPreferences.Editor prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit();
        prefs.putBoolean("notifications_team_pick",false);
        prefs.putBoolean("notifications_results", false);

        prefs.commit();


    }



    public class myWebClient extends WebViewClient {

        private Context context;

        public myWebClient(Context context) {
            this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);

            String CurrentURL = wv.getUrl();

            if (CurrentURL == "https://str8red.com/") {
                wv.evaluateJavascript("fromAndroid()", new ValueCallback<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onReceiveValue(String value) {
                        String[] separated = value.split(" ");
                        //separated[0]; // logged in True Or False
                        //separated[1]; // Notifications 1 or 0
                        //separated[2]; // More Notifications or 1 or 0
                        String loggedIn = separated[0].replace("\"", "");
                        String Notify1 = separated[1].replace("\"", "");
                        String Notify2 = separated[2].replace("\"", "");

                        SharedPreferences.Editor prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).edit();
                        prefs.putBoolean("notifications_team_pick",false);
                        prefs.putBoolean("notifications_results", true);

                        prefs.commit();
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }

    //Settings Button
    public void btnSettings_onClick(View view) {
        Intent intent=new Intent(this,SettingsActivity.class);
        startActvity(intent);
    }

    private void startActvity(Intent intent) {
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    //End of Settings Button

    //Play Button

    public void btnPlay_onClick(View view) {
        wv.loadUrl("https://str8red.com/selectteams/0/0");
        wv.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
    }
    //End of Play Button

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass a `context` as argument in `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)`.

The `this` you are passing is the `WebViewClient`.

Have a constructor which accepts Context in myWebClient.

```
private Context context;

public myWebClient(Context context) {
   this.context = context;
}

@Override
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
 .....

     SharedPreferences.Editor prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).edit();

}
```

And pass context while creating the WebViewClient:

```
wv.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient(this));
```

Comment: Many thanks for the swift response. Could you please elaborate as I don't fully understand.

Comment: I assume you are getting error at this line:                     `SharedPreferences.Editor prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit();`, aren't you?

Comment: You should pass a `context` as an argument there. But you are passing `this`. Inside an `Activity`, `this` means `context`. But that code is inside `WebViewClient`. So that `this` means `WebViewClient`. You should pass a context there.

Comment: Sorry Bob, I really am not getting what you're saying.  Can you give an example or a link to further detail.  Sorry :(

Comment: What I do get is that the this part is relating to the WeViewClient, what I don't get is the context part.  What should the context part be?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151305/discussion-between-alan-tingey-and-bob).